# Balanced delta source to Wye source by considering magnitude only is ok?

Tags: power, ac, three-phase, y-to-delta

I read and derived formulas for balanced delta source to Wye source; it is given by Vy = Vd / sqrt(3)<30 but in some places I see people only dividing by sqrt(3) for conversions are keeping angle 0, is it the correct way for conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one doesn't care about the angle but only the magnitude then
\$ V_Y = \frac {1}{\sqrt 3} V_{\Delta} \$ is all you need.

For example, if I have a delta-star transformer feeding an induction motor nobody cares if the phases are 30° out because it is completely isolated from the delta side. Only the voltage magnitude will matter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkr5Gg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Phasor representation of star (wye) and delta voltages in a three-phase system.*

It is a fairly trivial exercise to prove the √3 relationship between the phase to phase and phase to neutral phasors.